# How could I create sanic server which after getting request will return json file with necessary data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sanic

I want to create sanic server which returns json file with necessary information after accepting request. I will write function which add necessary data to json file later, so now I need returning of an empty json file after request

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest way to respond with `json`.

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic import response

app = Sanic("my_app")

@app.get("/some-json")
async def some_json(request):
    return response.json({})
```

I am a little unclear about your question though. Are you trying to respond with `json` in the body of the response, or to send back a file?

If a file, you could [do this](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html#file)

```py
@app.get('/some-json-file')
async def some_json_file(request):
    return await response.file('/path/to/file.json')
```